# How to prove that $\text{Ker}(A)=\text{Ker}(A^2)$ if $A$ is a normal operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-operator

Prove that $\text{Ker}(A)=\text{Ker}(A^2)$ if $A$ is a normal operator.

I know that that $\text{Ker}(A)\subseteq \text{Ker}(A^2)$, which I proved as follows:
$x\in \text{Ker}(A) \implies Ax=0\implies(AA)x=A(Ax)=0\implies x\in \text{Ker}(A^2)$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Why ${\rm ker}(A)\subseteq {\rm ker}(A^2)$? you should write that argument. What do you think about the other set-inclusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this should be clear from the spectrum theorem, it can be established directly.

If $A^2x=0$, then $$0=(A^2x, A^2x)=(Ax, A^*A^2x)=(Ax, AA^*Ax)=(A^*Ax, A^*Ax)$$

Thus $A^*Ax=0$, hence $$0=(A^*Ax, x)=(Ax, Ax)$$

So $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Any normal operator $A$ has the same kernel as its adjoint (since $\|Ax\|^2=(A^*Ax,x)=(AA^*x,x)=\|A^*x\|^2$), hence

$$A^2x=0\Rightarrow Ax\in\ker A=\ker A^*\Rightarrow0=(0,x)=(A^*Ax,x)=\|Ax\|^2.$$